# IronPython 2.7.4: SystemError while initializing a property

Tags: python, properties, ironpython

I have encountered a problem which I have been racking my brains over for a few hours now, and still cannot fathom why it is happening so I find myself turning to StackOverflow for help...

I am working on a fairly large application (made up of several script files) that executes using IronPython 2.7.4.

I have been able to simplify the code down to the piece that causes the problem.

The original script defines several properties in the same way as laid out below.
Yet this one, and *only* this one, causes the error.

It happens both when trying to import the script file, and when I run it as the entry point.

Here is the simplified `test.py` file:

```
1 class Test(object):
2    def __init__(self):
3        self._P = 'Hello'
4
5    def P():
6        def fget(self):
7            return self._P
8    P = property(**P())        # ERROR
```

And here is the console print out for when I try to run it:

```
$ ipy64 test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
File "test.py", line 8, in Test
SystemError: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

(I have also tried using `ipy` instead of `ipy64`; Makes no difference.

If anyone can point out what it is I'm missing then I'd be most grateful! :)

I am running Windows 7 64-bit Home Premium.
(I have used `prompt $$` in `cmd` to create the `$` in the command line, as the directory path is pretty long!)

Comment: What do you expect `P = property(**P())` to do?  P doesn't return anything, so P() is None, and you can't `**`-unpack `None`.  The CPython error message is more enlightening: `TypeError: type object argument after ** must be a mapping, not NoneType`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I was being silly...

In [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/), typing `property` and hitting tab, autocompletes to:

```
def foo():
    def fget(self):
        return self._foo
    def fset(self, value):
        self._foo = value
    def fdel(self):
        del self._foo
    return locals()
foo = property(**foo())
```

My problem was, in removing the setter and deleter for the property (as I did not require them)
**I accidentally removed the** `return locals()` **statement** which caused it not to work.

Yeah... Less said about that, the better! :))

Answer (score 0):

You missed `self` in function P

`def P(self)`:

Comment: ... among other things.